# GARCH variance vs standard deviation for volatility

Tags: volatility, garch, variance

in my series of questions related to GARCH and volatility I finally think I've got a decent grasp on it. You guys have been great help clearing up my questions for me.

My next question is just a confirmation of my suspicion. It's well known that in finance, volatility is typically understood to be the standard deviation of returns. However, GARCH analysis helps you forecast the *conditional variance* of a process.

Suppose I have an ARIMA-GARCH forecast for the log returns of a series. GARCH gives us the equations:

$$y_t = x'_t + \epsilon_t$$
$$\epsilon_t|\psi_t ~ N(0, \sigma_t^2$$
$$\sigma_t^2 = \omega + \alpha_1\epsilon_{t-1}^2 + ... + \alpha_q\epsilon_{t-q}^2 + \beta_1\sigma_{t-1}^2 + ... + \beta_p\sigma_{t-p}^2$$

These equations define the variance at time $t$, $\sigma^2_t$.

If my forecast returns a value of $0.05$ for the 1 step ahead forecast then I can simply take the square root of the forecast to get the conditional volatility - correct? So in this case the 1 step ahead forecast of volatility is:

$$\sqrt{0.05} = 0.1732$$

This *seems* correct to me, but I am having trouble finding people who are doing this and I want to make sure that this is sound.

Thank you!

Comment: I disagree with @Quantuple , No you can't, your forecasts return are differents of your forecast conditional variance process , and your model specification is wrong: the standardized error term ($\eta_{t}$) has a unit variance and the error is defined as the product of the std erros and the volatility process. $ \epsilon_{t} = \sigma_{t} \eta_{t} $ . Also you must include the polynomials of the lag operator (AR and MA terms) in the model specification. I recommend you to read more about the theory.

Comment: @Malick if the model is properly specified shouldn't the error terms approximate a white noise process?

Comment: yes the std errors $\eta_{t}$ should be a white noise but not the errors $\epsilon_{t}$ (with my notation) since they have an autoregressive structure implied by $ \sigma_{t} $. The model specification you show does not take into account the ARMA part (the cond. mean proces). This ARMA part has for errors terms $\epsilon_ {t}$ and not $ \eta_{t}$

Comment: @Malick maybe I did not understand the question but, for me, given the filtration $F_{t-1}$ the ARMA part is deterministic, hence only the last part matters and it's variance is $\sigma^2_$ which is measurable at $t-1$ no? J'ai peut être raté un truc ;)

Comment: @Quantuple, To me it looks like the conditional mean forecast is 0.05 (due to ARMA structure, not due to $\epsilon_t$, because $\mathbb{E}(\epsilon_t)=0$), which is unrelated to the conditional variance forecast as the latter concerns the conditional variance of $\epsilon_t$. I don't think the OP got the things right.

Comment: @Richard Hardy, aha. I thought OP computed $\sigma_{t+1}^2$ at $t$ (using the GARCH equation) and was simply asking if taking the square root indeed gave the conditional volatility...

Comment: @Malick I finally understand what you mean in the light of Richard's comment. You are of course right. This is a big misunderstanding on my side, sorry for that.

Comment: I have rectified my answer. Thanks for the eye opener.

Comment: @Quantuple oui la question de l OP n'était pas bien précise. En tt cas, thumbs up pr ta rapidité et pr le clin d' œil en Francais ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your question is: "Given all the information available up to time $t$, if I compute the 1 period ahead forecast $r_{t+1}$, is the conditional volatility over $[t,t+1[$ given by $\sqrt{r_{t+1}}$?", the answer is **NO**.

To compute the 1 period ahead conditional variance, you should use your model equations (see [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41509/what-is-the-difference-between-garch-and-arma/41514#41514) post which might help you better understand the ARMA-GARCH paradigm).

Here's an illustrative example. Consider an ARMA(1,1)-GARCH(1,1) model for the returns process:
\begin{align}
r_t &= a + b r_{t-1} + c \sigma_{t-1} z_{t-1} + \sigma_t z_t \\
\sigma^2_t &= d + e \sigma^2_{t-1} + f r_{t-1}^2 
\end{align}
with $\{z_t\}_1^\infty$ iid $N(0,1)$ variables such that:
$$\mathbb{E}\left[r_t \vert \mathcal{F}_{t-1}\right] = a + b r_{t-1} + \tilde{c} z_{t-1} $$ 
for the ARMA part (conditional mean model) and
$$\mathbb{V}\left[r_t \vert \mathcal{F}_{t-1}\right] = d + e\sigma^2_{t-1} + fr^2_{t-1} $$
for the GARCH part (conditional variance model).

Now assume you observe a series of $N$ returns $\mathbf{r} = \{r_1,...,r_N\}$. You calibrate your model (usually by maximum likelihood estimation) on these returns and you get a bunch of model parameters (here $a, b, c, d, e, f$). At this point, all you need to do is use the GARCH equation to compute the latent conditional variances. For this, you'll need an initial value $\sigma_1$ to initialise the recursion, in which case you'll have:
$$ \sigma^2_2 = d + e \underbrace{\sigma^2_1}_{\text{initialisation}} + f \underbrace{r^2_1}_{\text{$1^{st}$ observed return}} $$
$$ \sigma^2_3 = d + e \underbrace{\sigma^2_2}_{\text{computed @ step 1}} + f \underbrace{r^2_2}_{\text{$2^{nd}$ observed return}} $$
$$ \vdots $$
$$ \sigma^2_{N+1} = d + e \underbrace{\sigma^2_N}_{\text{computed @ step N}} + f \underbrace{r^2_N}_{\text{$N^{th}$ observed return}} $$
Now that you have the 1 period ahead conditional variance $\sigma^2_{N+1}$ just take the square root to get the conditional volatility.

The real question is how to get $\sigma_1$? This is usually part of the model specification and there are different ways to do it, see [this](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/26076/does-the-unconditional-variance-implied-by-a-garch-equal-the-sample-variance/26083#26083) post, especially the link in the comments of the accepted answer (REM: the notation used is $h_1 := \sigma^2_1$)

You can easily extend this approach to highest order GARCH models.

Answer (score 1):

let' s define a ARMA-GARCH model:

$y_{t} = \mu_{t} + \epsilon_{t}$
where $\mu_{t} $ is the conditional mean process (ARMA(p,q) part, $\mu_{t} = E(y_{t}|\mathcal{F}_{t-1})$)  .

The errors (or mean residuals) re defined by:

$\epsilon_{t} = \sigma_{t} \eta_{t}$

where $\eta_{t}$ is a white noise (0,1)

Then :

$Var[\epsilon_{t}]= \sigma_{t}^{2}$.

next see that :

$Var[y_{t} \vert \mathcal{F}_{t-1} ]=  E\left[( y_{t} - E(y_{t} ))^{2}\vert \mathcal{F}_{t-1}  \right]  = E\left[( y_{t} - \mu_{t})^{2}\vert \mathcal{F}_{t-1}  \right]  = E\left[( \epsilon_{t})^{2}\vert \mathcal{F}_{t-1}  \right]  = Var[\epsilon_{t}]$

so

$Var[y_{t}]= \sigma_{t}^{2}$.

> see that  $Var[y_{t} \vert \mathcal{F}_{t-1} ] \neq  E\left[( y_{t})^{2}\vert \mathcal{F}_{t-1}  \right]  $

---

Ex:
 AR(1)-GARCH(1,1)

$y_{t} =AR_{1}y_{t-1}+ \epsilon_{t}$

where

$\epsilon_{t} = \sigma_{t} \eta_{t}$

and

$\sigma_{t}^{2}  =w+ \alpha \sigma_{t-1}^{2} + \beta \epsilon_{t-1}^{2}$

$Var[y_{t} \vert \mathcal{F}_{t-1} ]=  E\left[( y_{t} - E(y_{t} ))^{2}\vert \mathcal{F}_{t-1}  \right]  = E\left[( y_{t} - AR_{1}y_{t-1})^{2}\vert \mathcal{F}_{t-1}  \right]  = E\left[( \epsilon_{t})^{2}\vert \mathcal{F}_{t-1}  \right] =Var[\epsilon_{t}]= \sigma_{t}^{2}$

now if you only compute the following as you suggest:

$  Var[y_{t} \vert \mathcal{F}_{t-1} ]=E\left[( y_{t} )^{2}\vert \mathcal{F}_{t-1}  \right] = E\left[( AR_{1}y_{t-1}+ \epsilon_{t} )^{2}\vert \mathcal{F}_{t-1}  \right] =...$

you won't find  $Var[y_{t} \vert \mathcal{F}_{t-1} ]=  \sigma_{t}^{2}$ (unless $AR_{1}$=0)

---

> To summarize you needs to model explicitly the conditional variance
>   process ( $\sigma_{t}$) to be able to forecast it, there is no way to
>   obtain it only from the cond. mean process, it seems rather logical.